# Onclick not firing on dynamically created td tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am required to run this on an environment that runs IE 8. Any suggestions as to why the 'setAttribute' sets the onclick, but it doesn't actually work correctly (not firing when clicked). I have gone over other examples and still, no response when I click what's in the table. Only the pre-existing p tags have the onclick function to run.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Video</title>
<!-- meta -->
<script>    
    var list = ["test", "test2", "test3"];

    function buildTable() {
        document.getElementById('tableArea').innerHTML = "<table border='1' id='mytable'><tbody><tr><td>Video Title</td></tr></tbody></table>";
        for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            addRow(list[i]);
        }
    }

    function addRow(content) {
         if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return;
         tabBody=document.getElementsByTagName("tbody").item(0);
         row=document.createElement("tr");
         cell1 = document.createElement("td");
         cell1.setAttribute ('onclick', 'getName(' + content + ');');
         textnode1=document.createTextNode(content);
         cell1.appendChild(textnode1);
         row.appendChild(cell1);
         tabBody.appendChild(row);
    }

    function getName(fileName){
    alert("hello");
        /*var htmlPlayer = '<embed type="application/x-mplayer2"' +
                        'name="mediaplayer1" autoplay="false" autostart="true"' +
                        'width="900" height="600" loop="false" controls="false"' +
                        'allowFullscreen="True"' +
                        'src="'+ fileName +'.avi">' +
                        '</object>';
        document.getElementById('videoPlayer').innerHTML = htmlPlayer;*/
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Page One</h1>

    <p id="videoPlayer">
        <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" 
            name="mediaplayer1" autoplay="false" autostart="false" 
            width="900" height="600" loop="false" controls="false" 
            allowFullscreen="True" src="">
        </object> 
    </p>

    <p onclick='getName("test");'>test</p>
    <p onclick='getName("test2");'>test2</p>
    <p onclick='getName("test3");'>test3</p>

    <p id="tableArea"></p>
    <script>buildTable();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you're missing quotes for your onclick attribute

```
cell1.setAttribute ('onclick', 'getName(\'' + content + '\');');
```

You might want to think of another way to pass that content along though other than string concatination. You could create a closure function that has access to the content variable.

```
cell1.onclick = function(){ getName(content); };
```

or, if your elements will contain that name and nothing else, you can pass their innerHTML to getName.

```
cell1.onclick = function(){ getName(this.innerHTML); };
```

Comment: Awesome - your second solution works for me. I tried that prior but I did not return the function. After a couple hours, you have allowed me to move on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
cell1.setAttribute ('onclick', 'getName(' + content + ');');
```

to

```
cell1.setAttribute ('onclick', 'getName("' + content + '");');//notice the quotes
```

You want to send a string, not an undefined object, so the double quotes are necessary to show that you are passing a string not an object.

--EDIT-- Working example

```js
var list = ["test", "test2", "test3"];

function buildTable() {
  document.getElementById('tableArea').innerHTML = "<table border='1' id='mytable'><tbody><tr><td>Video Title</td></tr></tbody></table>";
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    addRow(list[i]);
  }
}

function addRow(content) {
  if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return;
  tabBody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody").item(0);
  row = document.createElement("tr");
  cell1 = document.createElement("td");
  cell1.setAttribute('onclick', 'getName("' + content + '");');
  textnode1 = document.createTextNode(content);
  cell1.appendChild(textnode1);
  row.appendChild(cell1);
  tabBody.appendChild(row);
}

function getName(fileName) {
  alert("hello");
  /*var htmlPlayer = '<embed type="application/x-mplayer2"' +
                  'name="mediaplayer1" autoplay="false" autostart="true"' +
                  'width="900" height="600" loop="false" controls="false"' +
                  'allowFullscreen="True"' +
                  'src="'+ fileName +'.avi">' +
                  '</object>';
  document.getElementById('videoPlayer').innerHTML = htmlPlayer;*/
}

buildTable();
```

```html
<h1>Page One</h1>

<p id="videoPlayer">
  <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" name="mediaplayer1" autoplay="false" autostart="false" width="900" height="600" loop="false" controls="false" allowFullscreen="True" src="">
  </object>
</p>

<p onclick='getName("test");'>test</p>
<p onclick='getName("test2");'>test2</p>
<p onclick='getName("test3");'>test3</p>

<p id="tableArea"></p>
```

Comment: No cigar. Still nothing

Comment: can you upgrade to IE 9 or a better browser?

Comment: Sorry, no. This environment intends to stay with IE 8 for now.

Answer (score -2):

In order to successfully bind to a dynamically created element, you will be need to target its wrapper.

for example:

```
$(wrapper).on('click', targetElement, function(){
 ....the behavior you want
});
```

you can check out this blog post for more info: http://blog.ning-xia.com/accessing-dynamically-created-elements-with-jquery/

Comment: I am not familiar with JQuery. Is there a way to do this in vanilla JS?